# I want to iterate through JSON file to insert into table in PHP. I do not know how to iterate into every subarray. Help greatly appreicaited

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have been trying to iterate over JSON arrays to extract the data and upload it into a SQL server.

By searching online through other articles, I can recursively print out the data but am not quite sure on how to assign the values to a variable and query SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [gender] => female
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Miss
                            [first] => Melanie
                            [last] => Mcdonalid
                        )

                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [street] => Array
                                (
                                    [number] => 2039
                                    [name] => Smokey Ln
                                )

                            [city] => Orange
                            [state] => New York
                            [country] => United States
                            [postcode] => 78082
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [latitude] => -56.3075
                                    [longitude] => 116.5772
                                )

                            [timezone] => Array
                                (
                                    [offset] => +9:30
                                    [description] => Adelaide, Darwin
                                )

                        )

                    [email] => melanie.mcdonalid@example.com
                    [dob] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 1973-06-09T10:58:51.031Z
                            [age] => 49
                        )

                    [registered] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2004-09-22T10:38:38.464Z
                            [age] => 17
                        )

                    [phone] => (270) 521-5196
                    [cell] => (516) 737-7116
                    [picture] => Array
                        (
                            [large] => https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/51.jpg
                            [medium] => https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/51.jpg
                            [thumbnail] => https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/51.jpg
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [gender] => female
                    [name] => Array
```

I tried to brute force the SQL query by just creating one big table and then try to optimize it, but am having little to no luck.

Comment: You'll need at least 2 tables. Since there are multiple pictures for each user, you'll need a `user_pictures` table with a foreign key to `users`.

Comment: You could do some recursion to so that each child property is prefixed with the parent (e.g. `name_title`, `location_street_number`). You'd need to make sure those columns exist though - even possibly creating additional ones if it doesn't exist. If you know the exact property names and data type this isn't really an issue, but if you don't know the datatype, it could end up with a database table that is all `VARCHAR` columns as to ensure no data is transformed when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array of users, extracting each field into a variable. These variables can be used as the bindings for a prepared `INSERT` statement.

After inserting the user, use the `insert_id` property to get the auto-increment ID that was assigned. This can then be used as the foreign key value when inserting the pictures into another table.

```
$insert_user_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (title, firstname, lastname, street_num, street_name, city, state, country, postcode, latitude, longitude, tz_offset, tz_description, email, dob, age, reg_date, reg_age, phone, cell)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert_user_stmt->bind_param("sssissssffssssisiss", $title, $firstname, $lastname, $street_num, $street_name, $city, $state, $country, $postcode, $latitude, $longitude, $tz_offset, $tz_description, $email, $dob, $age, $reg_date, $reg_age, $phone, $cell);
$insert_picture_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_pictures (user_id, size, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$insert_picture_stmt->bind_param($user_id, $size, $url);

foreach ($data as $user) {
    $title = $user['title'];
    $firstname = $user['first'];
    $lastname = $user['last'];
    $street_num = $user['location']['street']['number'];
    $street_name = $user['location']['street']['name'];
    $city = $user['location']['city'];
    $state = $user['location']['state'];
    $country = $user['location']['country'];
    $postcode = $user['location']['postcode'];
    $latitude = $user['location']['coordinates']['latitude'];
    $longitude = $user['location']['coordinates']['longitude'];
    $tz_offset = $user['location']['timezone']['offset'];
    $tz_description = $user['location']['timezone']['description'];
    $email = $user['email'];
    $dob = $user['dob']['date'];
    $age = $user['dob']['age'];
    $reg_date = $user['registered']['date'];
    $reg_age = $user['registered']['age'];
    $phone = $user['phone'];
    $cell = $user['cell'];
    $insert_user_stmt->execute();

    $user_id = $conn->insert_id;
    foreach ($user['picture'] as $size => $url) {
        $insert_picture_stmt->execute();
    }
}
```